# Max height - change when window is resized?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a block grid in foundation, this has loads of images in it.

I would like set a max-height of the grid so that images after a certain height are not shown. I wish to show 2 rows and then hide the rest.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns my-grid">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-4 medium-block-grid-8 large-block-grid-9 text-center">
          <li><div style="background-image: url(my-img.jpg)"></div></li>
```

CSS

```
.my-grid{

    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
```

The above works and anything below 300px is hidden. I get into trouble though when the window is resized, 300px is no longer the desired height for 2 rows of images as the images are smaller for different media queries, my question is, how can I keep the max-height in relation to 2 rows of images?

Answer (score 0):

> ...the images are smaller for different media queries...

In that case, all you have to do is creating very similar media queries for the grid height. If your CSS to format images depending on screen height is something along these lines (assuming a `li` element wraps the image in its entirety):

```
@media (max-height: 900px) {
    .my-grid li {
        height: 150px;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 700px) {
    .my-grid li {
        height: 120px;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .my-grid li {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

... then we know exactly what condition is met when the image is downscaled. We can use that to also scale the grid itself:

```
@media (max-height: 900px) {
    .my-grid {
        height: 300px; /* 2*150 = two rows of images */
    }
}

@media (max-height: 700px) {
    .my-grid {
        height: 240px; /* 2*120 = two rows of images */
    }
}

@media (max-height: 500px) {
    .my-grid {
        height: 200px; /* 2*100 = two rows of images */
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this involve hundreds of media queries? The height of one row of images changes for every pixel change in browser width

Comment: Also I do not wish to mess with foundation block grid css and set a height for each li, thats what block grid is doing for me

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert on zurb-foundation. `the images are smaller for different media queries` implied a finite number of these... well, media queries that determine the height of grid images. If they are in-fact directly dependent on window height (eg. a fixed percentage), then I just recommend doubling that height percentage for the rows - if that is possible.

Comment: Why don't you fix the image dimensions so that a row will always have the same height?

Comment: Then the images will go over the top of each other when the screen is smaller.

Comment: Hum, could you illustrate your use-case using a jsFiddle or codepen ?